# Alternative to nested Else If statements with different outcomes?

Tags: vb.net

Is there any better way of handling nested else if statements that have different outcomes?

Here is an example of one of my nested statements to explain:

```
            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) = True Then
                Call InstallVS(computerName)
                If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) = True Then
                    Call PEC(computerName)
                    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) = True Then
                        Call RemoveSoftware(computerName)
                    Else
                        Call WriteLog(computerName & " lost connectivity while attemping to remove the temp software")
                    End If
                Else
                    Call WriteLog(computerName & " lost connectivity while Forcing Communication")
                End If
            Else
                Call WriteLog(computerName & " lost connectivity while attemping to Install")
            End If
```

I have a requirement to lots of these type of statements, some are smaller, some are a lot larger.

Comment: Note that in your program the message does not correspond with the action during which you lost connection. It shows the action following the one you'd like to be shown. The answer below gives correct results, because is establishes the message text BEFORE executing the action, while yours does it AFTERWARDS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method called `PingOrFail`, which will test connectivity or throw an exception otherwise, with a given error message. Then your code flow could look something like this:

```
Try
    PingOrFail(computerName, "attempting to install")
    Call InstallVS(computerName)

    PingOrFail(computerName, "forcing communications")
    Call PEC(computerName)

    PingOrFail(computerName, "removing temp software")
    RemoveSoftware(computerName)
Catch ex As Exception
    Call WriteLog (computerName & " lost connectivity while " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

And this is the PingOrFail method:

```
Public Sub PingOrFail(computerName as String, message As String)
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) = False
        Throw New Exception (message)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, however would that not try InstallVS, then try PEC regardless of if it fails the one above?
If the ping check fails at any point, it needs to stop what its doing and exit out of the if statement

Comment: Once an exception is thrown (I've added the PingOrFail method to show where it's thrown), execution will skip to the first place where that exception is caught - in this case, the Catch Ex As Exception statement. After that is handled (with the WriteLog) it will continue from that point onwards - it won't return to the point where the exception was thrown.

Comment: I guess you may be used to the On Error Resume Next form of error handling that was common in VBScript/VB6, but I much prefer the structured error handling of Try/Catch blocks.

Comment: I've never used VBScript or VB6.  I've jumped straight into VB.Net, new to programming if i'm honest :)   I am able to use the Try method inside a Do loop...right?

Comment: You can wrap any block of code with Try/Catch, yes, even inside a loop.

Comment: Avner, is there anyway I can stop it outputting "An exception occurred" in the messages?  I require it to say "Machine lost connectivity while 'the message passed to PingorFail'".   Currently it is outputting "Machine lost connectivity while An exception occurred during a Ping request."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8019/discussion-between-greg-hesp-and-avner-shahar-kashtan)

Answer (score 2):

These statements don't need to be nested, they could just raise exceptions if they fail.

```
Private Sub DoStuff(ByVal computerName As String)
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) Then
            InstallVS(computerName)
        Else
            Throw New Exception(computerName & " lost connectivity while attemping to Install")
        End If
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) Then
            PEC(computerName)
        Else
            Throw New Exception(computerName & " lost connectivity while Forcing Communication")
        End If
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) Then
            RemoveSoftware(computerName)
        Else
            Throw New Exception(computerName & " lost connectivity while attemping to remove the temp software")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: if it throws an exception, will that exit the "loop"?

Comment: Any line where it has a "Throw New Exception" statement will take it down to the "Catch ex As Exception" line, and into the block with the WriteLog statement. ex.Message will contain the text you're after.

Comment: I can't figure out why, but all that outputs is "An exception occurred during a Ping request", rather than the actual message im passing

Comment: This will be because the code...

    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName) Then

...is raising an exception, not returning true or false.